# Difference between " so much" and "as much"

Tags: usage

What is the difference between " so much" and "as much" ? Please explain their correct usage.

Comment: In (nearly?) all contexts, they're equivalent. Offhand I can't think of a context where you can't switch from one to the other, but ***as*** is definitely more common overall.

Comment: ...but it's usually *If you **so** much as bend the truth, I'll kill you!*, and *You shouldn't talk **as** much as him!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers They are most definitely not the same in all contexts. I liked her so much. I liked her as much as you like him.

Comment: Those are exactly the two usages presented first in my answer below, where I point out that *You **can't** swap either of those usages.* Come to that, they're the same two usages in my second comment above. But the distinction isn't all that clear-cut, which is why I gave a *third* possibility in the answer where some (mainly, *older*) speakers still use ***so*** in "comparative" (as opposed to "emphatic") contexts like *I haven't got **so** much money as you.* But I tend to interpret that usage as "part-emphatic" anyway, even if the original source never intended any such nuance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You start out in your first comment with an inaccurate statement. It's very clear that you do regardless of how you are now providing caveats...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you complain so much. [a lot]

I don't know why you complain as much as that other kid. [comparative]

"as much" *as a comparative is not always spelled out*:

"I don't like him as much." [compared to some unnamed person the speakers know about already.]

If you *so much as* do x, you will be in trouble.

That use of so much as is an adverbial idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 0):

There's been [a significant usage shift](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20so%20much%20as%20you%2Cnot%20as%20much%20as%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) over the last couple of centuries...

[image]

...but obviously the real-world context in which people say *not **so / as** much as you* hasn't changed significantly. To my mind, that's all the evidence we need, to say the two are "interchangeable".

Equally obviously, ***as*** should be the preferred choice for learners in (almost?) all contexts today. *Except* in certain "emphatic" contexts like #1 below, where there's no obvious *alternative* being referenced...

> 1: *I've got **so** much money I don't really need a job*
> 2: *I've got **as** much money as you*

You can't swap either of those usages. But note that if #2 is *negated*...

> 3: *I haven't got **so** much money as you*

...then ***so*** is at the very least "acceptable" - but becoming less common as time passes (most of us use ***as*** in context #3 today).

Comment: They are  not interchangeable: I don't like her as much as  you do. is not: I don't like her so much.

Comment: I don't think you understand the significance of my chart. Unless you're going to claim that *the real-world context in which people say "not so / as much as you" **has** changed significantly* (which I think is implausible), the chart clearly implies that *usage has changed over time.* I have gone into some detail above (and in my comments) to set out how the *current* favoured usage split differentiates, but it's misleading to claim that the older usage is "incorrect". We wouldn't want to encourage learners to think they're finding "mistakes" all over the place in older texts.

Comment: Never mind. It's too much trouble. The negation was not part of the question.